# Android: Facebook like button doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to integrate Facebook "like" button into my Android app. I'm using Facebook SDK 4.1.2.

My app has the Main Activity with Navigation Drawer using fragments. One of the Fragments has the ListView. I need Facebook "like" button in every list item. I'm using custom BaseAdapter to construct the list items.
I don't have problems with Facebook signing in and with getting posts from some Facebook page.

But I faced the next problems:

1. The "Like" button doesn't have any likes count, it just looks like this

[image: 1]

By the way, is it possible to make this button looks like this?

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [jonathandoctor.net](http://www.jonathandoctor.net/images/facebook_like_button_big-small.jpg))</sub>

2. My "like" actions don't make any effect. I press the "like" button, some screen appears and fastly closes, and then I can't see any changes with the button, and the Facebook object (some page post) doesn't get my like (I check it via browser). In other words, My like button doesn't keep records of whether my liked button pressed or not. And also the like action doesn't succeed.

What am I missing with this task?

Here are parts of my code:

MainActivity.java

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    OpenFacebookSession();

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        LikeView likeView = (LikeView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_view);
        likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
        likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.
            AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);

        likeView.setObjectIdAndType(someID,//some Facebook object ID
                                    activity-launchmode/en",
                                    LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
        return convertView;

    }


}
```

feed_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

    <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/like_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/feedImage1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unable to see the second image

Answer (score 0):

Use of the Like button requires app approval, so during development, only users with **Admin/Developer/Tester** roles in your app can access it. Once it's approved, then any user can use the feature.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect Solution to make this work is as below.

Here we are considering that you have already generated the facebook app and **entered the Hash_key** and also you have **added your account as tester** if not.

Add this to your xml view.

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/like_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then Add this to your OnCreate Method

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
     LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BUTTON);
    likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
    likeView.setObjectIdAndType("https://www.facebook.com/Rultech",LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
```

Note: LikeView.Style.BUTTON can use changed as per your need.

Then Add the below code to Manifest.

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider_fb_app_id"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Then onActivityResult add this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**There might be a glitch if the Facebook App is not Installed on the phone.**

Finally Run the app. This will work for sure we have tested it for **FACEBOOK SDK 4.0.1** not sure for above version.